# Scrape data from a url within a webpage using beautiful soup. Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data (insta id and followers count) from a url inside the webpage: ,
https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india

The element id of the url is : @priyankachopra

Similary I want to scrape data from all links in the same table

Can someone tell me how to do this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get("https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the data directly in the HTML. You can extract the data you need by just using `beautifulsoup`

Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable

tb = PrettyTable(['Name', 'Insta_ID', 'Followers'])
url = 'https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india'
resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_='table-responsive-sm')
td = table.findAll('tr')

for i in td[1:]:
    temp = i.select_one("td:nth-of-type(3)").text
    name, insta_id = temp.split('@')
    followers = i.select_one("td:nth-of-type(6)").text
    tb.add_row([name.strip(), insta_id.strip(), followers.strip()])

print(tb)
```

```
Sample Output:

+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|              Name             |          Insta_ID         | Followers |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|     Priyanka Chopra Jonas     |       priyankachopra      |   57.9M   |
|      Jacqueline Fernandez     |       jacquelinef143      |   45.9M   |
|    URVASHI RAUTELA Actor    |       urvashirautela      |   31.7M   |
|          Kapil Sharma         |        kapilsharma        |   28.7M   |
|        Sachin Tendulkar       |      sachintendulkar      |   27.1M   |
|          Amanda Cerny         |        amandacerny        |   25.5M   |
|             Mia K.            |         miakhalifa        |   21.9M   |
|         KARTIK AARYAN         |        kartikaaryan       |   19.7M   |
```

Comment: is there a way i could open the link and scrape followers count from there. 
eg: click on @priyankachopra and scrape data from that page
Similary open first 1000 profiles on that table.

Comment: Yes you can. Go to this page: ```https://starngage.com/app/global/influencers/priyankachopra``` (you can get this link from the table) and scrape whatever data you need.

Answer (score -1):

Some JavaScript is being used to render the table, so `requests` fails to grab the table html. Instead, use `selenium` to simulate a web browser visiting the site and then pass the `page_source` to `BeautifulSoup`.

I then iterate over the rows of the table, saving each `insta_id` and `follower_count` into a list of dictionaries before converting everything to a `pandas` `DataFrame`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = "https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False # page didn't fully load HTML in headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
driver.close()

rows = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')

influencers = []
for row in rows[1:]: # skip header row
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    insta_id = '@' + cols[2].text.split('@')[1]
    follower_count = cols[5].text
    influencers.append({'insta_id': insta_id, 'follower_count': follower_count})

df = pd.DataFrame(influencers)

print(df)

                insta_id follower_count
    0    @priyankachopra          57.9M
    1    @jacquelinef143          45.9M
    2    @urvashirautela          31.7M
    3       @kapilsharma          28.7M
    4   @sachintendulkar          27.1M
    ..               ...            ...
    95       @tonykakkar             4M
    96     @reem_sameer8           3.9M
    97  @mominamustehsan           3.9M
    98           @bpraak           3.9M
    99        @djbravo47           3.9M
    
    [100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use Selenium for this. BeautifulSoup works just fine.

Comment: @Ram The non-Selenium version you posted does not work. I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'` coming from the line `td = table.findAll('tr')`. `requests` is not finding the table html since I assume some Javascript is still running to populate the table.